# JSP not rendering using Spring Boot and MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jsp

I am trying to run a JSP in Spring Boot, but all that shows up is the word `welcome` and not my actual content.  The JSP is called after doing a call to MongoDB.  I am also getting these exceptions when I make a call to MongoDB from my Java code.

`com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:553) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:444) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:295) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:106) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:63) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:109) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:570) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:441) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted`

welcome.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en" ng-app="employeeApp">
<head>
    <title>Frank's App</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <style>
            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <h2>Frank's App</h2>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Employee Number</th>
                <th>Pay Rate</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.lastName }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.empNumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.payRate }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public String welcome(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employees", getEmployees());
    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping("/getEmployees")
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    MongoDatabase db = getDatabase();
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection(COLLECTION);
    Document query = new Document();
    List<Employee> employees = collection.find(query, Employee.class).into(new ArrayList<Employee>());
    return employees;
}

private MongoDatabase getDatabase() {
    CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry =     org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
            MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),     org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
    MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("testdb").withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
    return database;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use JSP in your HTML code, it's Angular framework. Angular won't read data which you pushed as "employees" attribute in the controller.

Instead this

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.lastName }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.empNumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.payRate }}</td>
</tr>
```

Use JSP syntax, like this

```
<c:forEach var="employee" items="${employees}">
            <tr>
                <td>${employee.firstName}</td>
                <td>${employee.lastName}</td>
                <td>${employee.empNumber}</td>
                <td>${employee.payRate}</td>
            </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

[Read more about the JSP](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm)

You can also remove all Angular (attributes suffixed with `ng`) elements if you would like to build webpage only with JSP.

Comment: This didn't work.  I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Are you sure that you open the right web page? You should see at least `Frank's App` instead `welcome` message.

Comment: Did you debug the application to ensure that you have at least one employee in `testdb` database?

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug through Spring Boot, but I have manually verified through MongoDB that there is data in the collection I'm trying to access.  This is not in the `testdb` database, by the way.  This is through a database I created for this application.

Comment: I just figured out how to debug from Eclipse, but I am now getting exceptions from the database call.  I have edited the original post to reflect this.

Comment: I think you should ask another question, because we are now try to solve two problems (at least) one with database connection and the second with passing data to model (solved)

Answer (score 0):

Verify the following things

1. Check your mongodb server is running or not. Server not running may cause the above exception.
2. Check the monogdb dbname, host and port in application.properties file

   spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost

   spring.data.mongodb.port= *****

   spring.data.mongodb.database=dbName
3. Check these two entries too

   spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/

   spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

Comment: This isn't working either.  I ran this in debug mode and the call came back without exceptions, but with no data either, and I know there is data because I put it there manually myself.